# AngularJS ng-repeat refresh with new API call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

Currently working on an application where I'm doing an API call to get the data and then using `ng-repeat` directive to populate the table on the view.

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat="request in requests">
        <td md-cell>{{request.name}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.email}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.application_name}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.created_user}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.request_type}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

And in the controller, a user makes a new request and it adds a row to the database and after the success dialog comes up, I want to make a new request to the API to get the new row that the server generated, so I want to make a new API request.

So, I contact the API and get all the requests again and want to *replace the data on the table with the refreshed data from the API*

When the API call is successful, it calls this function from the promise:

```
var onRequests = function(response) {
  $scope.requests = [];

      response.forEach(function() {
          //Processing here and pushing to the new array
      });
  });
};
```

But, on creating this new array I'm assuming that *the reference to the original array, which the scopes of the ng-repeat pieces have, is lost.*

So, I'm trying to get a way for it to just refresh the ng-repeat table with a new array.

Here are things I've tried:

- New array and then `$apply`ing
- Keeping same array reference and just removing everything and doing
  it again, but this seems like a hacky way and I want an elegant
  solution
- Using $rootScope instead for the array, which seems to work for some
  reason...

This is how I did the $rootScope one, which works (but seems hacky):

```
 var onRequests = function(response) {
      $rootScope.requests = [];

          response.forEach(function() {
              //Processing here and pushing to the new array
          });
      });
    };
```

For some reason *this works*, and I don't know why it does. That's why I don't understand.

**The problem**: When I make the api call, this function is called and the `$scope.requests` is set to an empty array (does this change the address/lose references?), and then populated with the new data from the API. I am wondering if *this doesn't update the ng-repeat child scopes with the new data*.

I know that normally if you change the `ng-repeat` `$scope` array, it should update the DOM, but since I'm setting it to an empty and new array and then populating that new array, it seems to be losing the reference to the array. 
That's why it seems to work if I go and pop every element on the array rather than just setting it equal to a brand new empty array (eg `$scope.requests = [];`

---

### What I Want

### Regardless if this is the best way to solve it. All I want to do *is update the ng-repeat table with the new data from the API call.*

If anyone could help me out, that would be awesome. I've read around on other questions similar and couldn't seem to find anything helpful or exact along what I'm trying to do, from what I've found, it hasn't worked.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, I've read over about a dozen other posts that have similar wording and none were exact to what I am trying to do as I said, so before flagging as duplicate, know that a lot of the other ones didn't work as solutions.

Comment: Try putting `forEach` inside a *timeout*, either a `setTimeout` or `$timeout` of 0 seconds, to make changes in the next digest cycle.

Comment: @SatishKumar, just tried that, didn't work :(

Comment: Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FjuhssCvHwwHXTHjw3IT?p=preview), The idea is same as your issue. Just use `$timeout`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want to replace the previous data with the new data, both of your examples should work. Do you need to keep a reference to the old data? If so, why?

Comment: The fact that using $rootScope works indicates that there is something else going on that is not provided in the question. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… 
 **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash When I am making the new API call, I am getting completely new data, and I am trying to repopulate the table based on this new data. But, when I get the new data, it doesn't update the DOM, but DOES update the actual array. I was thinking it was because the child scopes have a reference to the old array, but the new array that I have the new data on is the updated.

Comment: @georgeawg My bad, I will put more stuff in to the question. Apologies on not being clear.

Comment: It is not clear why the DOM is not updating. One possibility is that the method that calls the API is not integrated with the AngularJS framework. The $http service which is part of AngularJS framework has no problem when updating with a new reference to an `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is your question:

> So, I'm trying to get a way for it to just refresh the ng-repeat table
>   with a new array.

The short answer is this:

```
$scope.requests = newArrayOfRequests;
```

Or, what you have works, too:

```
//clear the array. I don't why you would need a reference to the old array,
// but if you do, then
//$scope.old = requests;
//then
$scope.requests = [];

response.forEach(function() {
  // do your processing
  $scope.requests.push(processedRow)
});
```

That's it. In AngularJS, that's all you have to do. That is the magic of AJS binding.

Now, there are some performance improvements that you can make by using `track by` in conjuction with your `ng-repeat`. But, this is all you have to do to refresh the `ng-repeat`.

The longer answer has to do with DOM nodes. AJS DOES INDEED keep track of each thing that is added to `ngRepeat` using generic ID's that it creates (if you inspect your table in dev tools you can actually see these IDs as attributes). However, this does not help you unless those IDs can be mapped back to your data. Luckilly you can specify that it use a unique ID from the actual data using `track by`:

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat="request in requests track by request.some_unique_id">
        <td md-cell>{{request.name}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.email}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.application_name}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.created_user}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.request_type}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{request.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

What this does is allows AJS to re-use DOM nodes that it previously created from the first time the data was loaded instead of recreating them each time you load new data.

When you load the new array, AJS only has to update the value of each row, or in your case, it only has to add a single DOM node for the new row that is returned by the API

But that doesn't change how the data is refreshed. Simply assign a new array to the `$scope` variable, or clear it and push new data. That's all there is to it.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do yes! But, for some reason, when I do load this new array into the $scope array that ng-repeat uses, it doesn't update the DOM. I was thinking maybe the child scopes that ng-repeat creates don't have a reference to the new array because the new array is created just by $scope.requests = [] and then populating it? When I do what you suggested, it doesn't seem to update the Dom, but does update the array correctly. Thanks for the in depth reply! What do you think would be a correct way to format this?

Comment: Also, just to be clear, I don't need a reference to the old array, sorry if I came across like that. I literally just want the table to repopulate the data with the new API call, but when I set `$scope.requests = [];` I am concerned that the scopes created on the ng-repeat rows lose the reference because now $scope.requests points at the new array rather than the one that populated the table. that is why it works if I pop every element off the array rather than setting it equal to a brand new array. So, with that being said, what's a good way to go about the problem?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. If you are not seeing the data in the table update, then you may have a deeper problem that we can't see from your code.@georgeawg is right